# ArrayFormula not filling cells

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"test"; IF(AND(M2:M>=80,LEFT(H2:H,2)>=20),"Yes","No")})
```

My formula isn't expanding beyond the first cell. Not sure what I'm missing. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND()` operation is applied to all values of column and returning single result. Use dynamic array formula to return result as separate value. Try `MAP()` function like-

```
={"Test";MAP(A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A)),B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(a,b,IF(AND(a>=80,LEFT(b,2)>=20),"Yes","No")))}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so it's almost working.

={"Test";MAP(M2:INDEX(M2:M,COUNTA(H2:H)),H2:INDEX(H2:H,COUNTA(M2:M)),LAMBDA(M,H,IF(AND(M>=80%,LEFT(H,2)>=20),"Yes","No")))}

but it is only checking for the value in M not H & M.

Comment: Try this one `={"Test";MAP(M2:INDEX(M2:M,COUNTA(M2:M)),H2:INDEX(H2:H,COUNTA(M2:M)),LAMBDA(M,H,IF(AND(M>=80%,LEFT(H,2)>=20),"Yes","No")))}`.

Comment: `80%` here `%` percentage may be an issue? Check it carefully.

Comment: Doesn't appear to have changed anything. Same issue.

Comment: Maybe if I explain what I'm trying to do it will help. I want to check if H2:H >= 20 and if M2:M >= 80%. Problem with cell H is that it has a numeric value and text. Example: "19 CHI". So I am trying to extract the numeric value from the cell then check if it is >= 20.

Comment: I'm not... the solution solved one issue but caused another.